# Hiding the progress bar in the adapter from the activity section

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I have a progrees bar in my adapter section and I want to change it from the activity section.

**Adapter**

```
interface PreparedOnItemDetailClickListener {
        fun onClick(
            orderDetail: PreparedOrdersResponse,
            view: View,
            preparingDetailProgressBar: ProgressBar
        )
    }
```

**Adapter-ViewHolder**

```
dclass PreparedViewHolder(private val binding: ItemPreparingBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(
        data: PreparedOrdersResponse,
        _preparedOnItemClickListener: PreparedOnItemClickListener,
        preparedOnItemDetailClickListener: PreparedOnItemDetailClickListener
    ) {
        binding.apply {
            detailAreaLinearPreparing.setOnClickListener {
                preparedOnItemDetailClickListener.onClick(
                    data,
                    it,
                    binding.preparingDetailProgressBar
                )
                preparingDetailProgressBar.visible()
            }
            linearTime.setOnClickListener {
                preparedOnItemDetailClickListener.onClick(
                    data,
                    it,
                    binding.preparingDetailProgressBar
                )
                preparingDetailProgressBar.visible()
            }
            
}
```

**fragment**

I can successfully capture the listening event in the fragment section, but I cannot hide the progress bar.
By the way, I can hide the view.

```
 override fun onClick(
        orderDetail: PreparedOrdersResponse,
        view: View,
        preparingDetailProgressBar: ProgressBar
    ) {
        // TODO: PREPARED DETAIL ON ITEM CLICK
        view.isClickable = false
        Log.e("ORDERDETAIL", "onClick: " + orderDetail.id)
        detailOrderDialog(orderDetail, view,preparingDetailProgressBar)
    }
```

**detailOrderDialog**

I want to hide it in the dialog section because I want the progress bar to be hidden when the dialog opens.

```
private fun detailOrderDialog(
        orderDetail: PreparedOrdersResponse,
        view: View,
        preparingDetailProgressBar: ProgressBar
    ) {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val bindingDialog =
            DialogDetailBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(binding.root.context),
                binding.root,
                false
            )
        dialog.setView(bindingDialog.root)
        val alertDialog = dialog.create()
        bindingDialog.apply {

            preparingDetailProgressBar.gone()

            cancelImageView.setOnClickListener {
                alertDialog.dismiss()
                view.isClickable = true
            }

            menuImageView.setOnClickListener {
                view.isClickable = true

        
        }
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true)
        alertDialog.show()
    }
```

I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the code was working, but I was hiding the progress bar first and then showing it.

Adapter-ViewHolder

```
binding.apply {
    detailAreaLinearPreparing.setOnClickListener {
    preparingDetailProgressBar.visible() //will be here
        preparedOnItemDetailClickListener.onClick(
             data,
             it,
             binding.preparingDetailProgressBar
              )
               //preparingDetailProgressBar.visible() won't be here
            }
            linearTime.setOnClickListener {
    preparingDetailProgressBar.visible() //will be here
                preparedOnItemDetailClickListener.onClick(
                    data,
                    it,
                    binding.preparingDetailProgressBar
                )
               //preparingDetailProgressBar.visible() won't be here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving view elements to the part, you can move `position` information.

You can then use the method below.(with `Fragment` or `Activity`)

```
fun hideProgressBar(position: Int) {
    
    val holder = yourRecylerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) as YourViewHolder?
    holder?.preparingDetailProgressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
    // You can perform all the operations in this section. Like showing Alert Dialog.
}
```

The important detail here is to use `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`. It is practical.

Comment: Where should I write this code? Can you write in more detail?

Comment: You can write it in Fragment and Activity.

Comment: but it has no position value

Comment: I updated my question maybe it will be better for you